# How to not append /home/ When Clicking href Django

Tags: django

If I'm at a web page `myapp.com/home` I have a nav bar at the top that leads to `delete_confirm.html`. This is within my `home.html` page that contains the link

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    User Settings
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'delete_confirm_view' %)">Delete Account</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Here is my `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', home_view, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    path('delete/', delete_user, name='delete'),
    url(r'^signup/$', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('paste_list/', paste_list_view, name='paste_list'),
    url(r'^$', home_view),
    path('<str:custom_uuid>/edit', edit_view, name='edit_paste'),
    path('<str:custom_uuid>/', detail_view, name='detail'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('delete_confirm_view/', delete_confirm_view, name="delete_confirm_view" )
]
```

And the relevant part of `views.py`

```
@login_required
def delete_confirm_view(request):
    return render(request, "delete_confirm_view.html", {})
```

The error I'm getting is: `The current path, home/{% url 'delete_confirm_view' %), didn't match any of these.` I'm wondering how I can not include the `/home` portion that is appended to the URL being checked. OR, how I can forward to the required page correctly.

Comment: why do you have two urls `path('home/', home_view, name='home'),` and `url(r'^$', home_view),` hitting the same view? I guess you don't need the first one?

Comment: I have that in case the user goes to either `myapp` or `myapp/home`. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: ok try moving the `url(r'^$', home_view),` to the top in urls.py

Comment: @SammyJ No difference, it seems.

Comment: What is the project url? is home/ in there?

Answer (score 0):

```
in your <project>/urls.py

from django.urls import path, include, re_path # url renamed as re_path in django2.0
from <your_app> import urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include("your_app.urls")), # probably, you are using `home` prefix here.
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```